# NHibernate 3.2 - Pre and Post Delete event listeners not invoked

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am working against an implementation of NHibernate 3.2 with several custom entity state change listeners: PreDelete, Delete, and PostDelete. The DeleteEventListener is defined by inheriting a custom type from DefaultDeleteEventListener, but the others are simply implementing the IEventListener interfaces.

The body of the CustomDeleteEventListener follows:

```
protected override void DeleteEntity(IEventSource session, object entity, EntityEntry entityEntry, bool isCascadeDeleteEnabled, IEntityPersister persister, ISet transientEntities)
{
    if (entity is BaseEntity)
        HandleEntityAssociations(session, (BaseEntity)entity);

    if (entity is ISoftDeletable) 
    {  
        var e = (ISoftDeletable)entity;
        Utility.SetTrackingInfo(e as BaseModel);

        e.Deleted = true; 

        CascadeBeforeDelete(session, persister, entity, entityEntry, transientEntities); 
        CascadeAfterDelete(session, persister, entity, transientEntities); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        base.DeleteEntity(session, entity, entityEntry, isCascadeDeleteEnabled, persister, transientEntities); 
    } 
}
```

In my tests, I've found that the `OnDelete()` listener is always called *before* the `OnPreDelete()` and `OnPostDelete()` listeners, and the Pre and Post listeners will never fire if `base.DeleteEntity()` is not called. This doesn't make any sense to me- I would expect the order to be: `OnPreDelete()`, `OnDelete()`, `OnPostDelete()`.

When I examined the callstack, I noticed that `OnDeleteEvent()` is triggered by an underlying call to `FireDelete()` invoked immediately after a call to `ISession.Delete()`, but `OnPreDeleteEvent()` is fired by a listener to `OnFlush()`- completely disconnected from the call to `OnDeleteEvent()`.

There is almost no documentation for these listeners, only a handful of blogs using them for this-and-that. Does anyone know how these work in NHibernate 3.2, and why I am seeing the behaviors that I am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, the `OnDelete`, `OnUpdate`, ... are used to do things like validation, or modify the actual entity being deleted, updated, inserted. This occurs pretty much at the start of the pipeline, see e.g. ["NHibernate interceptor magic tricks, pt. 4"](http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/18/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-pt-4/)

> When a delete occurres, the very first thing NHibernate does, is calling `IInterceptor.OnDelete(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)` method. It does not provide any flow control and is simply called by the default `IDeleteEventListener` before scheduling the real delete action.

Also refer to the other parts of that blog series for more information.

The `PreDelete` and `PostDelete` event listeners are called in the [`DeleteAction`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/c85d038dce8ba87bd3f4de2458b4ef6e2497f7f8/src/NHibernate/Action/EntityDeleteAction.cs), which itself is created by the `DefaultDeleteEventListener`  (i.e. the class you are deriving from) in its `DeleteEntity` method, and added to the session's action queue. Thus they are invoked **after** the `DeleteEventListener` invokation.

The `Pre...` events happen just before the actual command is being issued. At that point it is too late to force changes to the command by modifying the entities themselves, although you can work with the command's parameters (and make sure to also apply those changes to the corresponding entity's fields), or perform an additional action (e.g. insert an audit record) by using a child session. Returning `true` from any of these `Pre...` listeners will veto the change, returning `false` will result in executing it.

You may want to read this blog post: [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener & IPreInsertEventListener](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener). It relates to the update and insert listeners, but for the delete, the reasoning will be similar.

> Those allow us to execute our custom logic before the update / insert is sent to the database. On the face of it, it seems like a trivial task, but there are some subtleties that we need to consider when we use them.
>
> Those hooks run awfully late in the processing pipeline, that is part of what make them so useful, but because they run so late, when we use them, we have to be aware to what we are doing with them and how it impacts the rest of the application.

It appears that "awfully late" means:

> the ADO.Net Command that will be executed as soon as the event listener finish running.

Since NHibernate has its roots firmly in the Java Hibernate version, which has the same type of listeners and events, that is another potential source of information for more official documentation on this topic.

Comment: This analysis is extremely informative, thank you @Alex. One question- you said that returning `true` from the pre terminates the delete. Would that not be `false`, or is it actually asserting `veto = PreDelete()`?

Comment: @NathanTaylor, as counter intuitive as it sounds, returning `true` means veto: `veto |= listener.OnPreDelete(preEvent);`